# The difference among To-Do, note, memo, and reminder?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I consider developing an iOS app which lets my users add a one-line text or 6 seconds speech quickly, just after they opened the app. It presumes them add the scheduled tasks, such as *shopping for the X department store* or *finish filling the utility bill* or *go to Y hospital*, and they will be mostly executed within the day or within a few days.

But I stumbled on how I can name the app. Specifically, the terms `To-Do`, `Note`, `Memo`, and `Reminder` just hit on my mind.

While the difference between `memo` and `note` can be discovered easily on the Web, I can't tell the differences if `reminder` and `to-do` are added to the mix.

How can I tell them apart the others and for my app, which is the best to clarify the purpose well? I don't think `note` is a good for my purpose because it doesn't presume such a long text, but it is just my guess.

Comment: You want "reminder", not "remainder".

Comment: "Remainder" was good, what ***remains*** to be done, the name of your new app :)

Answer (score 2):

To-do and reminder are very similar, however, they definitely have some very different implications.

For example, a "to-do" generally implies a list of tasks, whereas a "reminder" generally implies a single task.

The biggest disparity is in the implication of action: a "to-do" implies a static task and a "reminder" implies an active task - I review a to-do list, I'm *reminded* of a reminder.

I think your app will determine which word fits better. Based off of your short description, I would chose "To-Do". It seems like it's a collection of tasks as opposed to a reminder system. Though, it's very likely that you'll have a reminder element, "To-do" fits a more ambiguous vibe (*Do laundry by Friday* type tasks).

Edit - In addition - most calendar apps have very good "reminder" elements already. What is missing, in a glaring and frustrating way, is the "To-Do" style reminder system. "Here's what needs to be done this week..." as opposed to "Remind me of this at this time on this day...". The former is certainly underrepresented in the app world.